# Phone Authentication in Firebase for signed apk misbehaves

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented phone authentication for firebase using the following [phone authentication]

It works for debug apk but does not work for signed apk. I have generated the SHA1 for signed apk and registered in firebase and downloaded the latest google-services.json file and put it in my project.What else i need to do for signed apk for phone authentication in firebase?